# AngularJS - how to get unique values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could anyone please help me on getting unique values for `Math.random()`? I want to have random number in each 3x3 cell, but so far I'm manage to get only [THIS](http://i62.tinypic.com/2ufr71k.png) result (same number in all 5 cells).

**script.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("RandomCtrl", function ($scope){
    $scope.showRandom = function () {
        return Random;
    };
});



var Random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
```

**index.html:**

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">

            <div ng-controller="RandomCtrl">

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{showRandom()}}</td>
                        <td>{{showRandom()}}</td>
                        <td>{{showRandom()}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{showRandom()}}</td>
                        <td>{{showRandom()}}</td>
                        <td>{{showRandom()}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{showRandom()}}</td>
                        <td>{{showRandom()}}</td>
                        <td>{{showRandom()}}</td>
                    </tr>

                </table> 
            </div>
```

Comment: Use `$scope.showRandom = function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1); };` instead.

Comment: You may want to look into directives with isolated scope - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `var Random` on the global scope when your app initializes and then returning that instance every time.  You need to get a new random number each time:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("RandomCtrl", function ($scope){
    $scope.showRandom = function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    };
});
```

Or, if you do infact want `Random` on the global scope, make *it* the function, and then call it:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("RandomCtrl", function ($scope){
    $scope.showRandom = Random;
});

var Random = function() {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
}
```